# How do I replace a double asterisk Noncommutative multiplication symbol in an output?

Tags: replacement

For a better overview in my output, I would like to replace ** with nothing.
Since

```
foobar /. ** -> ""
```

does not work I ask for help.

The ** is the Noncommutative multiplication.

Reference: [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you are talking about the string "**", the expression ** is not a valid Wolfram Language expression, henceforth it will never be an output of any expression. What language are you using?

Comment: Can you give an example input in which you'd like the asterisks removed? By the looks of it, you're working with strings, in which case you need `StringReplace` or `StringDelete` and specify appropriate string pattern you want  to delete: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringPatterns.html

Comment: I am using the noncommutative multiplication. And since my output is big I just want to leave it out after calculation. Since I know its an multiplication https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html

Comment: user66499, i suggest you  add the information in your comment to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foobar = c ** b ** a;

foobar /. NonCommutativeMultiply[a__] :> Infix[NonCommutativeMultiply[a], "\[InvisibleTimes]"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user66499, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing from @kglr, but taking advantage of [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) instead of [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
expression=c**b**a
(* c**b**a *)

FullForm[expression]
(* NonCommutativeMultiply[c,b,a]*)

Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Format[NonCommutativeMultiply[k__]]:=Infix[NonCommutativeMultiply[k], "\InvisibleTimes]"];
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

expression
(* c\[InvisibleTimes]b\[InvisibleTimes]a *)

FullForm[expression]
(* NonCommutativeMultiply[c,b,a] *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

In [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) I opted for using the Notation package for this purpose when the user is in a Notebook. This option, which is not on by default, is activated by typing `NCSetOutput[NonCommutativeOutput->True]`, which basically runs the command:

```
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[FilledSmallCircle]"], NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

As @rhermans' solution using `Format`, only the output format is changed, not the original expressions, as would happen with @klgr's solution. Yet the main advantage is that the user can now copy and paste from other cells in the notebook and the formatted content will be correctly interpreted as `NonCommutativeMultiply`. A disadvantage is the annoying Notation pallet that comes up every time you load the Notation package. Does anyone know how to stop that from showing up?

I would also advise against using an invisible times if you are planning on mixing commutative and noncommutative products as that would make them virtually indistinguishable.